# JavaFx TableView - update items from another controller

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a TableView that I am populating with 2 columns (Key and Value) from a database. When I click on a table row, I open a new scene which has a text area that shows the Value column and allows one to edit it. I choose to go with a separate UI for editing the contents of value column as it contains a prettyfied JSON document and having an in place edit in the table would have been cumbersome.

```
dataTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Map.Entry<String, String>> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                 showDataPopup(dataValue.getKey(), dataValue.getValue());
            });
            return row;
        });
```

```
private void showDataPopup(String key, String value) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("tableDataPopup.fxml"));
            Parent dataRoot = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("Data Viewer");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(dataRoot, 800, 500));
            DataPopupController dataPopupController = fxmlLoader.getController();
            dataPopupController.loadDataTextArea(key, value, this);
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error loading tableDataPopup.fxml", e);
        }
    }
```

Now, in the tableDataPopup scene, I allow the value to be edited. I have a save button which should save the edited document back to the table and close the scene. Here's my save method

```
 public void saveEditedDocument(ActionEvent event) {
            //code to save document to db
            mainController.refreshTable(docIdLabel.getText(), dataTextArea.getText());
            Stage stage = (Stage) editCancelButton.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
        } 
      ...
```

I have a refreshTable method in my main controller. Main controller has all the TableView components and logic.

```
    public void refreshTable(String docId, String docVal) {
        logger.info(": {}", dataTable.getItems());
    }
```

I need help figuring out how to update the cell value that was changed in the popup dialog. I'd rather avoid having to stream the whole table and look for the key column and update the value. I am looking for a way to pass the cell index to the data popup and have it pass it back to the refreshTable method. Then use it to directly update the cell and then call dataTable.refresh() method to refresh the data table.

I am struggling with where to even start on this. Any pointers would really help...

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score -1):

I guess i figured it out. May not be an elegant solution, but this works for me.

I am passing the index of the row that was clicked on to my dataPopupController

```
dataTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<Map.Entry<String, String>> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                 showDataPopup(dataValue.getKey(), dataValue.getValue(),row.getIndex());
            });
            return row;
        });
```

```
private void showDataPopup(String key, String value, int index) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("tableDataPopup.fxml"));
            Parent dataRoot = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("Data Viewer");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(dataRoot, 800, 500));
            DataPopupController dataPopupController = fxmlLoader.getController();
            dataPopupController.loadDataTextArea(key, value, this, **index**);
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error loading tableDataPopup.fxml", e);
        }
    }
```

And I updated the refreshTable method in main controller to update the item based on the index

```
    public void refreshTable(String docVal, int tableIndex) {
        logger.info(": {}", dataTable.getItems());
        logger.info("Table value is: {}", dataTable.getItems().get(tableIndex).setValue(docVal));
        dataTable.refresh();
    }
```

And in my popup controller, I just pass back the index when I call refreshTable method

```
public void saveEditedDocument(ActionEvent event) {
//        Todo - refresh table after save
        try {
            mainController.refreshTable(minifyData(dataTextArea.getText()), tableIndex);
            Stage stage = (Stage) editCancelButton.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException exception) {
            saveStatusLabel.setText("Malformed JSON, please correct");
            logger.error("Malformed JSON - {}", exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

May not be the most elegant way to do this, but in a pinch, it works for me.

Comment: refresh is (nearly, there are corner cases which this doesn't seem to be) always wrong .. correctly set up, the update happens automagically. so with this you are smearing paint over a major problem (that will bite again)